# Android app crashes showing webview logs

Tags: android, webview

My android app often goes not responding and then crashes printing the following log:

```
12-16 00:43:49.788 27523-27523/com.robocats.main W/linker: /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x38c70
12-16 00:43:49.788 27523-27523/com.robocats.main W/linker: /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x3
12-16 00:43:49.908 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309150)
12-16 00:43:49.928 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
12-16 00:43:49.928 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
12-16 00:43:49.938 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
12-16 00:43:49.938 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
12-16 00:43:49.948 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 5331-5332)
12-16 00:43:49.948 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
12-16 00:43:49.958 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
12-16 00:43:49.978 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-16 00:43:50.028 27523-27523/com.robocats.main I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
12-16 00:43:50.328 27523-27523/com.robocats.main D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
12-16 00:43:57.608 27523-27534/com.robocats.main I/art: Thread[7,tid=27534,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x55982e3fc0,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
12-16 00:43:58.088 27523-27534/com.robocats.main I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

The logs are coming from webview, but I'm not at all using webview in my application. Any pointers here?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. From `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider`, can you point out how you are querying information? It can either be a failure in your library (and thus can be updated), or it can be some failure on a library-in-a-library. If you are not using `WebView`, something is. You can debug it, and check where/why it fails.

Comment: Ok. 'CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider' is probably being used by 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+' to fetch my client's credentials. This might be using the webview then. How do I debug this?

Comment: From your `LogCat`, check the file: `12-16 00:43:58.088 27523-27534/com.robocats.main I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'` [Check this link  on a Traces tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html). You can also update your device "Android System WebView" application.